# C# Conditioning if the Value In The Database Column Reach the Value Zero

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm creating if else conditional statement if the column "ending_balance" reach the value 0. So, the adding of new payment must not be insert. Here's my code.

```
private void btn_payment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Data select = new Data();
select.Connection();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ending_balance FROM tblsalary_payments WHERE customer_id='"+customer_id+"'", select.connect);
MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();

       if(txt_payment.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Payment is Required");
            return;
        }
        else if (dr["ending_balance"].ToString() == "0")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Balance Is Already Zero");
        }
        else
        {
        ... // Do the Insert Query if the Validation Passed
        }
    dr.Close();
 }
```

I don't know why I can still insert the query. Even though I edited the column value into zero.

Comment: This code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: sir @Drew how can I dump it? :(

Comment: instead of converting it to string, compare it to database field type value type. For exampleIf field type int then to zero

Comment: Sir @Saurav there's an error if I put == 0 :(

Comment: Sir @Drew Please comment your answer below. I got an idea to dump it and I figure how can I fix. Now I fix it :D Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Does this work out??Convert.ToInt32(dr["ending_balance"].ToString())== 0

Comment: No sir. I want you to create an anwer, then I'm gonna "Mark as Answered" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas to debug:

put a breakpoint or dump this out dr["ending_balance"].ToString() ... perhaps the string="0.00" and not "0"... that is afterall your last line of defense.

Don't compare to a string, but compare the Value to 0.

Use msgbox() to examine pesky problems, a way to dump information (albeit a modal/blocking thing).

Comment: Thank you sir. :) God bless! Amen. :)

Comment: You're welcome if I helped at all. You have a lot of great debugging tools and stepping thru code there with Visual Studio. Harness it :>

Comment: Yes sir! I'll remember your advices! :D

Comment: php programmers have about 1/10th of the power to debug that you have at your fingertips !

Answer (score 1):

You can validate it directly without converting ToString.. since you are validating integers, also check the datatype of your table structure, make sure you are validating the same datatype to avoid converting integer to string.

Also, it is better to use stored procedure than creating your sql statements on the behind code to make it more secure.

Regards